# *NgIf block in Angular does not toggle with two event functions

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ng-if, angular-ngfor

I need to show and hidden(perfectly - totally clear to original state) block with images with two buttons.

For this I tried to make this job with NgIf block and boolean variable, but it works only with one button.How to separate toggling?

```
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="submit()">
          Find Cats!<img
            src="../../../assets/cat-sit.png"
            class="btn-image"
            alt="cat"
          />
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent">
          Clear space...<img
            src="../../../assets/cat-run.png"
            class="btn-image"
            alt="cat"
            onclick="clear()"
          />
        </button>
```

// block, that I need(perfectly to render such one (empty) every time I use clear()).

```
<div *ngIf="show" id="img-container" class="images-container">
  <div *ngFor="let cat of cats" class="cat-container">
    <mat-card
      ><img mat-card-sm-image src="{{ cat.url }}" class="cat-image" alt="cat"
    /></mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Funtions:

```
submit() {
    this.catsInfo.getCats(); // this part call service with restApi and data for cats
    if (!this.show) {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }
    
  }
clear() {
        if (this.show) {
        this.show = !this.show;
         }
   }
show: Boolean = false;
```

Comment: Which button works?

Comment: Submit. After click NgIf block is shown. I experimented with toggling - if submit makes show =!show, it also hides block but it isn`t correct way to work.

Comment: Are you sure that clicking submit does not reload the website?

Comment: yes - it also adding new photos on every click (and that`s correct).

Comment: So submit button should only show the block and clear button should only hide?

Comment: Submit()- starting process of getting photos and showing the block.
Clear() - at least hide the block, but perfect - to adding new block or 'restart' initial state of block (like before any photos)

Comment: NOTE: use `src="assets/cat-run.png"` or `src="./assets/cat-run.png"`, Angular copy the folder assets in dist/assets and is in dist where you have the index.html (we can change this behaivour in angular.json) so the path should be relative to "index.html", **not** to the folder where you have the component (Angular don't matter this)

Answer (score 1):

Your clear button is using `onclick="clear()"` so the Angular function will not be called. Change this to `(click)="clear()"` and it should work.

You can also simplify your `clear()` and `submit()` functions:

```
submit() {
    this.catsInfo.getCats(); // this part call service with restApi and data for cats
    this.show = true;
    
}
clear() {
    this.show = false;
}

show: Boolean = false;
```

Comment: I tried this before my question. And tried one more time after your answer. It didn't help

Comment: @MrBlack D'oh! I just noticed that in your code you have the `onclick` on the `<img>` not the "clear space" `<button>` element! When you tested it, were you clicking the button or the image within the button?